# Migrate from TFS 2010 to TFS2008

Tags: tfs-migration

We have some unusual situation and need to migrate from TFS2010 to TFS2008. Does anybody know is it possible to make ?

Comment: TFS2008 -> 2010 involved a complete reworking of the database. I doubt there is anything to undo this. So either you'll need to build your own with the migration toolkit, or lose your VC and item histories.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need full fidelity - that is, you don't need to transfer shelvesets over, you don't mind rebuilding reports, etc - then you may be able to synchronize your TFS2010 server to a TFS2008 server using the [Team Foundation Server Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f854dd59-8eeb-4673-8d9a-ae012989bfa2).

We use these internally at Microsoft to mirror between various servers with regularity, and with good success.